how to convert a tensorflow weights folder (containing .data, .index and another unknown file name checkpoint) to .pb format and to .tflite?
I have a zip file containing the above 3 described files... zip file
First, I loaded a pretrained model, provided some input tensor and then loaded the model in training mode....
model = parseq(pretrained=True)
input_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 32, 128, 3], maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32)
# out = model(input_tensor)
out = model(input_tensor, training=True, target=['hello'], return_model_output=True, return_preds=True)

Then, I used this code provided by the chatgpt to convert the files in the zip file to .pb format
I extracted the files from the zip file and stored it into parseq-tf dir....
# Define the model directory where your files are located
model_dir = '/content/parseq-tf'

# Create a new model (should match the original model's architecture)
# model = YourModelClass()  # Replace with the actual model class

# Load the weights from the checkpoint files
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model)
latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
checkpoint.restore(latest_checkpoint).expect_partial()

model_save_path = "/content/parseQ"
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_save_path)

on trying this I got the following error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-55d1cae3481c> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 model_save_path = "/content/parseQ"
----> 2 tf.saved_model.save(model, model_save_path)

32 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/doctr/models/modules/vision_transformer/tensorflow.py in tf__call(self, x, **kwargs)
     12                 assert ag__.ld(W) % ag__.ld(self).patch_size[1] == 0, 'Image width must be divisible by patch width'
     13                 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).projection, (ag__.ld(x),), dict(**ag__.ld(kwargs)), fscope)
---> 14                 patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(B), ag__.ld(self).num_patches, -1)), None, fscope)
     15                 cls_tokens = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).repeat, (ag__.ld(self).cls_token, ag__.ld(B)), dict(axis=0), fscope)
     16                 embeddings = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).concat, ([ag__.ld(cls_tokens), ag__.ld(patches)],), dict(axis=1), fscope)

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/saving/legacy/saving_utils.py", line 147, in _wrapped_model  *
        outputs = model(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filey06r7ztp.py", line 10, in tf__call
        features = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).feat_extractor, (ag__.ld(x),), dict(**ag__.ld(kwargs)), fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filebyh298ce.py", line 14, in tf__call
        patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(B), ag__.ld(self).num_patches, -1)), None, fscope)

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'par_seq' (type PARSeq).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/doctr/models/recognition/parseq/tensorflow.py", line 329, in call  *
            features = self.feat_extractor(x, **kwargs)  # (batch_size, patches_seqlen, d_model)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filebyh298ce.py", line 14, in tf__call
            patches = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).reshape, (ag__.ld(patches), (ag__.ld(B), ag__.ld(self).num_patches, -1)), None, fscope)
    
        TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'patch_embedding' (type PatchEmbedding).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/doctr/models/modules/vision_transformer/tensorflow.py", line 89, in call  *
                patches = tf.reshape(patches, (B, self.num_patches, -1))  # (batch_size, num_patches, d_model)
        
            TypeError: Failed to convert elements of (None, 128, -1) to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'patch_embedding' (type PatchEmbedding):
          • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 128, 3), dtype=float32)
          • kwargs={'training': 'False'}
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'par_seq' (type PARSeq):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 128, 3), dtype=float32)
      • target=None
      • return_model_output=False
      • return_preds=False
      • kwargs={'training': 'False'}

